# Tables with a ManyToOne relationship, how to select rows from master if none of the linked rows fulfill a condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

**foos**:

| id | f_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx |
| 2 | yyy |
| 3 | zzz |

**foo_bars**:

| id | foo_id | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | false |
| 2 | 1 | false |
| 3 | 1 | false |
| 4 | 2 | true |
| 5 | 2 | false |
| 6 | 2 | true |
| 7 | 3 | false |
| 7 | 3 | true |

Each `foo` should have each an *active* `foo_bar`, and only one. Because of a poorly designed process, it sometimes happened that either **more than one** `foo_bar` was set to `active=true`, or that *no* `foo_bar` was set to active. Neither is a valid scenario.

I need to find those rows on `foos` where the linked `foo_bars` rows with active are != 1.

E.g. in the above scenario I'd like to get:

```
1,xxx
2,yyy
```

Can I accomplish this with a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be a good use of the `HAVING` clause in a `GROUP BY` query:

```
select
  f.id, f.f_name
from foos f
left join foo_bars b on f.id = b.foo_id
group by
  f.id, f.f_name
having
  count (*) filter (where b.active) != 1
```

Comment: Postgres rocks is right.  The more I use it, the more blown away I am.